# Download file with specific name in php

Tags: php

ok once my "button" is pressed then

```
if (isset($_POST['DOWNLOADLOADER'])) {
  //???
}
```

i need it to download

```
example.com/test.exe
```

with name

```
anothertest.exe
```

i have tried this

```
$original_filename = '4324ffsd34.jpg';
$new_filename = 'my_new_filename_is_detailled.jpg';

// headers to send your file
header("Content-Type: application/jpeg");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($original_filename));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $new_filename . '"');

// upload the file to the user and quit
readfile($original_filename);
exit;
```

Comment: ? pls helpppppp

Comment: `i  have tried this` ... Ok and what exactly was the problem? (P.s please don't say "it doesn't work" or "nothing is download" ...we need to understand how the code behaves, compared to what you expected. Please do some proper debugging and then report back. If you don't know how to debug with PHP there are plenty of beginner guides available online. (I recommend sticking with simple var_dump or logging techniques to start with, rather than messing about with something like xdebug)